# Getting SkAndroidCodec::NewFromStream returned null from downloading mage to ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview

There's some interesting things going on with downloading an image from a url. I'm currently getting a SkAndroidCodec::NewFromStream returned null when posting the image to

createBitmap for creating bitmap for file (this is the main issue)

```
private Bitmap createBitmap(String imageFile){
    try {
        File f = new File(imageFile);
        InputStream l = new FileInputStream(f);
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));

        String str = "";
        while((str = bf.readLine()) != null){
            Log.d("testing",str);
        }

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        BufferedInputStream bs = new BufferedInputStream(l);
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bs,null,options);
        bs.reset();

        //boolean support = l.markSupported();
        //l.reset();

        options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(l,null,options);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        Log.d("Exception",ex.toString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

`urlImage` function used for creating image file and setting in `ImageView`

```
private boolean urlImage(String url) {
    String[] test = url.split("/");
    String imgFile = mainDir.concat("/".concat(test[test.length - 1]));
    File f = new File(imgFile);

    Log.d("Image Src", imgFile);
    String t = (f.exists()) ? "true" : "false";
    Log.d("Exists", t);

    try {
        if (!f.exists()) {
            f.createNewFile();

            URL urlImage = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlImage.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(3000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(3000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(imgFile));

            String str = "";
            while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                bw.write(str);
                Log.d("something else",str);
            }
            bw.close();
            os.close();

            Bitmap m = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            is.close();

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                Log.d("HTTP OK","responsed properly");
                imageSrc.setImageBitmap(m);
            }
            createBitmap(imgFile);
        }
        readFile(imgFile,"image");
        return true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.d("Exception", ex.toString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

`readFile` function for creation of file after download

```
private void readFile(String file,String fileType){
    Log.d("File",file);
    try {
        Log.d("createBitmap","bitmap being created");
        if(fileType == "image") {
            mainBitmap = createBitmap(file);
            imageSrc.setImageBitmap(mainBitmap);
        }else{
            readTextFile(file);
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        Log.e("Exception",ex.toString());
    }
}
```

Really unsure about what is causing the issue. Followed all the errors posted on here that might cause the issue, and the solutions and I was unable to do anything to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't able to quite figure out what the issue was, but there's some very interesting options on here that have been giving out the wrong information.

There shouldn't be a double buffered image, especially if you've already created the image file.

Although writing the image file should be capable from the HTTPConnect there's no way of figuring out if the file is an image by writing the file directly. (possibly an issue with the line by line grab without the creation of a new line (or it could just be that it process the information differently, whatever the case it faults out as an actual image file))

There's a few other really big issues that can be fixed with the built in commands for the android studio system, but to actually need to use one of the system processes to create a image file would be against certain coding practices used for conformity of file types.

I'm guessing it's something that the creators of the android system felt needed to remove added code from the now defunct jpeg virus that was used in the late 1990's early 2000's

This would be the code needed to process the image in a standard manner.

```
private File createImageFile(String url) throws IOException{
    Date date = new Date();
    String[] urlArray = url.split("/");
    String imgFileString = mainDir.getPath().toString().concat("/".concat(urlArray[urlArray.length - 1]));
    File f = new File(imgFileString);

    Log.d("Image File Tag",imgFileString);

    if (!f.isFile()) {
        String[] test = url.split("/");
        String imgFile = mainDir.getPath().toString().concat("/".concat(test[test.length - 1]));

        URL urlImage = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlImage.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(3000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(3000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

        Log.d("testing", conn.getContent().toString());

        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            Log.d("HTTP OK", "responded properly");
        }

        Bitmap btm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) urlImage.getContent());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);

        btm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos);
        fos.close();
    }
    return f;
}
```